# Word or short phrase meaning "the act of bring about fatal consequences"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or short noun phrase that means "the act of bringing about fatal consequences"?

Also, can it be generalized for "the act of bring about <adjective> consequences"?

Example:
_______ is a common characteristic of problems of this sort. 
(Problems of this sort bring about fatal consequences for whatever it affects)

**EDIT:**

I'm looking for something like `homicide` (which was suggested by another user but unfortunately somebody else downvoted the answer and it got deleted), except more general; `homicide` is "the act of bringing about fatal consequences for one person by another" and I'm looking for just "the act of bringing about fatal consequences (for anything by anything)".

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence showing how you would use this word?  Wouldn’t ***kill*** or ***destroy*** work in most cases?

Comment: @Jim I've added an example! The problem with *destruction* or any other similar word is that it's ambiguous whether it's active or passive. For example, `Destruction is a common characteristic of problems of this sort` could mean that the problem destroys or the problem gets destroyed. I was hoping for something that is unambiguously active, but I guess that's more of a problem with English syntax as opposed to a particular choice of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obliteration**.

> obliterate
>
> *verb*
>
> [transitive, often passive] to remove all signs of something, either by destroying it or by covering it so that it cannot be seen:
>
> *The missile strike was devastating - the target was totally obliterated.*
> *All of a sudden the view was obliterated by the fog.*
>
> [transitive] to make an idea or feeling disappear completely:
>
> *Maybe she gets drunk to obliterate painful memories.*
>
> ([Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obliterate))

Answer (score 1):

A nice *verb* meaning fatal termination is **to scuttle**, e.g. a project (*the scuttling of the project...*):

> to abandon or destroy (plans, rumors, etc.) ([The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scuttle))
>
> to stop something happening, or to cause a plan to fail ([Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scuttle))

Its original meaning is

> to intentionally sink a ship, especially your own, in order to prevent it from being taken by an enemy ([Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scuttle))
>
> to sink (a vessel) deliberately by opening seacocks or making openings in the bottom ([The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scuttle))

Comment: Or "scupper" with the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion! I learned a new word! Unfortunately, `scuttle` seems to be restricted to plans/projects (and ships!). I'm looking for something more general that can apply to both abstract and concrete things (you can't say `*The fire scuttled the entire forest.`).

Comment: @ZacharyLim But this is a valid answer to the question you asked. (I had just been about to suggest **terminal**.) If you want to add another criterion to your question, then edit it to include your comment.

Answer (score 1):

### Termination

> verb
> 1.
> to bring to an end; put an end to:
> *to terminate a contract.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/terminate))

This applies more to ending inanimate things that people but I think that's what you want

Comment: @jxh*Termination* works!

Comment: Good point, edited.